# shopify I need to check if current page is a collection page and not a single product page

Tags: shopify, liquid, liquid-layout, dotliquid

I am trying to check if my current page is a collection page not a single product page in some collection.

I mean for example if someone goes to collection page of shoes then I can check using collection.handle == 'Shoes' but if I select a product from that page then it will still give me true But I want my condition to be true on if it is collection page.
Thanks for your Help!

Answer (score 20):

Use this simple way with [`template`](https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/objects/template):

```
{% if template contains 'collection' %}
    Do something
{% endif %}
```

As Shopify evolves you can now use this:

```
{% if template.name == 'collection' %}
    Do something
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Works also if you need to check if you are on a product page with if template contains 'product'.

Comment: Be careful... any product with a name containing "collection" will register true for this.   Granted that chance is rare, but it's out there.

Comment: Absolutely not. The variable checks template name. So if you are on a product page, the variable contains «product». Even if {{ product.name }} contains the word Collection, this is not related to template name.

Comment: I think I understand.  I had that mixed up with the location href.  Cool, thanks

Answer (score 11):

A safer alternative to avoid rare cases where templates are badly named would be to use `request.page_type` - see [the Shopify docs](https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/liquid/reference/objects/request#request-page_type)

```
{% if request.page_type == 'collection' %}
  Do something
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I don't think this is correct, template.name is not the user given name of the template but actually the template type: https://shopify.dev/api/liquid/objects/template#template-name

Could be a change since you wrote the answer, I have no idea :)

Answer (score 6):

I would use:

```
{% if template == 'collection' %}
  Do something
{% endif %}
```

Because if you use `contains` and not `==` (equal to) you may run risk of it changing down the line if you ever created a new template which contained the word collection?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this in condition.

```
{%if request.page_type == "collection" %} 
--- True if visit collection page or sub collection page. ---
{% endif %}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For defining a site wide page type I like this :

```html
<body _pagetype="{{ request.page_type | handle }}">
```

Answer (score 0):

since templates subsets have a ".", like collection.xyz, page.xyz, product.xyz I would use this code

```
{%- assign t = template | split: '.' | first -%}
{%- if t == 'page' -%}
{%- endif -%}
{%- if t == 'product' -%}
{%- endif -%}
{%- if t == 'collection' -%}
{%- endif -%}
```